# Filter by /category with mstest.exe and VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, mstest

**Edit:** This is a Visual Studio 2017 issue. Repeated the same procedure with VS2015 and all works as itended.

I have created a simple unit test project in VS2017 with two unit tests.
These tests are marked with the category "Ores" as shwon below:

```
[TestClass]
public class Copper
{
    [TestCategory("Ores"), TestMethod]
    public void CheckCopper()
    {
        DataMiner locMiner = new DataMiner();

        string result = locMiner.GetCopper();

        Assert.AreEqual("Copper", result);
    }
}
```

Now i try to run this test with mstest.exe via commandline with the /category filter.
The complete call is: mstest /testcontainer:TestSystem.dll /category:Ores

MSTest.exe is linked through the Path variable:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE;"

**I get the "No test to execute" message.** It doesnt matter if i write the category as "Ores" or Ores. Without the /category filter, mit test are run as intended.

Failed testrun with category.
[image]
No problems without category.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the friendly help of the MS staff i found a solution.

First a clarification: 
**mstest.exe is not intended to support VS2017 created MSTestV2 assemblys.**
Maybe i didnt dig deep enough or it is bad documented...

Anyway, **vstest.console.exe is the proper way to execute command line based unit testing with this configuration.**

But there is a different pitfall: There are 2 versions of the vstest.console.exe installed with VS2017.

**The outdated, not working one:**
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" which is version 15.0.0.0

**The version to use:**
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" which is version 15.0.26720.2

Finally a sample of a working execution of a VS2017 MSTestV2 created test assembly with filter active:
[vstest.console.exe works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to8xJ.png)